# How to autherize user in asp.net Identity using permissions instead of roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I am trying to utilize Identity for a new application that I am working on. The minimum info that is available about it is making it hard to understand.

Based on what I understand about Identity, I can create roles (i.e Admin, Super User, Users...) and for each action in the controller I can restrict whether a role can access the action or not. This an a decent approach for typical application. But in my application I need a deeper control on the access level. I need to be able to have more control not a role base autherization.

In a typical application I can add this over an action method `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` in a controller, and only people with `Admin` will be able authorized to access it.

But, I want to be able to add individual permission and not sure if this is possible using Identity. (Perhaps something to do with Claims?)

Here are my thoughts, I want to be able to do something like this

```
// In a Razor view I want to be able to do this
// Note: HasPermission is not real method, but is something I am posting
//       to explain what I am looking for
if(User.HasPermission("Edit Account")){
 // Show the Edit button
}

if(User.HasPermission("Add Account")){
 // Show the Add Button
}
```

Then, in the action methods I want to do be able to do something like this.

```
[Authorize( HasPermission = "Edit Account")]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    // Handle the edit
}

[Authorize( HasPermission = "Add Account")]
public ActionResult Add()
{
    // Handle the addition
}
```

The application will have many permission (i.e Edit Account, Add Account, Delete Account ....) I will assigned multiple permission to one user. The user with the permission `Add Account` will be able to add account.

Can something like this be done with Identity out of the box? How can I get started without complicating the problem?

Comment: You can use the existing Asp.Net Identity mechanism and create your own `function` table where roles will be linked to functions. Then you can interrogate that `db` based on that to give access where appropriate.

Comment: Can't claims help here?

Comment: I am not sure since you are going to create a new table that has no connection with the existing Identity mechanism. You can come with a logic to do custom checks in the override method `OnAuthorization`

Comment: i don't necessary need to create anything new. I just want to be able to use some type of permission check instead of doing role check,

Comment: I see what you mean. You can have a look at this doc. https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html just as a guide.

Comment: Also these articles might be of help: https://dotnetcodr.com/2013/02/11/introduction-to-claims-based-security-in-net4-5-with-c-part-1/ and http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1

Comment: I am not clear on how/when do I create the claims. Are claims something temporary per session or is something permanent and is associated with the user? Then can I use the claim type to see if the user have access to edit? like so `[Authorize(ClaimType = "Edit Account")]`

Answer (score 0):

Claims tell you *who* the user is, not what the user can do. For example, their may be a claim for the user's first name, their email address and so on. There may also be claims for the user's roles, or groups they belong to (there is a subtle difference, but let's ignore that for now). For example, there may be role claims stating the user is an accountant and a manager.

As you noticed, these claims don't tell you what the user can do. It may be the case that an accountant can edit an account, but the claims won't tell you that. Somewhere somehow, you'll have to make a translation from roles (and other claims) to permissions (as you call them).

Unfortunately, there is no standard component in the .NET Framework to do that. The only thing that ever came close was [AzMan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server-2008/bb897401%28v=msdn.10%29), but that is now deprecated.

That means you have two options:

You can role your own. It's not too difficult. Basically, you need a data structure with a many to many relationship between roles and tasks, and a many to many relationship between tasks and individual, fine-grained permissions. The Azman model can be a good source of inspiration.

The alternative, which many people take, and for simple applications is probably good enough, is to hardcode the roles in the application. That's where `[Authorize(Roles = "Accountant")]` comes in. Obviously, this model requires recompilation whenever the organization of the business changes, but that may be OK if it doesn't happen too often.

Unfortunately, there is no better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Identity workflow by adding Permission concept to the base. The most important thing you should care about is the relation between the current model and new added functionality. I did that in my latest project and publish it as an open source [Permission Extension to Identity 2 membership system here](https://github.com/Arminkhodaei/Identity-Permission-Extension).
You can read the Readme file and also feel free to ask your question or extend the library yourself.

As a short example you can use it like this:

First approach:

```
// GET: /Manage/Index
[AuthorizePermission(Name = "Show_Management", Description = "Show the Management Page.")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
{
    //...
}
```

Second approach:

```
// GET: /Manage/Users
public async Task<ActionResult> Users()
{
    if (await HttpContext.AuthorizePermission(name: "AllUsers_Management", description: "Edit all of the users information."))
    {
        return View(db.GetAllUsers());
    }
    else if (await HttpContext.AuthorizePermission(name: "UnConfirmedUsers_Management", description: "Edit unconfirmed users information."))
    {
        return View(db.GetUnConfirmedUsers());
    }
    else
    {
        return View(new List<User>());
    }
}
```